# Do we need to check that objects were actually allocated?

Tags: objective-c

In most of the Objective-C examples I've been reading, as well in the Objective-C documentation, objects are always checked for successful completion before use.

For example:

```
MyObject *myObject = [[MyObject alloc] init];
if (myObject){
    //do stuff with the object
}
//stuff beyond here is probably not going to work if myObject is nil
```

Won't this make it hard to trace bugs? I'm not sure why allocation would fail other than low memory, but I've never seen a check like this done in Java (the language I'm migrating from) right after initializing an object.

I suppose it would make an app very convoluted if you checked every single allocation and tried to react to failed allocations. I guess you could show an error message to the user in many cases, but the number of branches in the program would probably double.

But in the examples I've seen, they don't do anything when allocation fails, beside skipping some code that would be necessary for the user to see what they expect on screen. It seems like if failed allocations really happen much at all in practice, and you're following this coding style, the result would be blank screens, unsaved documents that the user thinks got saved, corrupted data that the user and programmer are unaware of, etc.

EDIT: Here's an example from Apple's tutorial "Your Third iOS App: iCloud".

```
- (NSMetadataQuery*)textDocumentQuery {
    NSMetadataQuery* aQuery = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
    if (aQuery) {
        // Search the Documents subdirectory only.
        [aQuery setSearchScopes:[NSArray
                    arrayWithObject:NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope]];

        // Add a predicate for finding the documents.
        NSString* filePattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"*.%@",
                    STEDocFilenameExtension];
        [aQuery setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K LIKE %@",
                    NSMetadataItemFSNameKey, filePattern]];
    }

    return aQuery;
}
```

Comment: I have never seen code do this in such a simple case. Can you offer a real example that you've seen?

Comment: at least in ios, if your `alloc` return `nil` for memory reason, your app will get killed by os anyway.

Comment: @Chuck I added an example.

Comment: @xlc Thanks, that's helpful to know.

Comment: Interestingly, if that's a pre-ARC example it is in violation of Apple's own standards for returning a retained object without "new" or one of the other special words in the method name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initializers should return `nil` if initialization fails, this could for example happen if `initWithFile:` is given a non-existent path.

In Objective-C you can send messages to `nil` (unlike e.g. C++ where you can't call a method on `NULL`), so checking `if (object)` is not necessary before operating on that object. On the other hand, if you want to add the object to an array you should check that it is not nil:

```
SomeClass *anObject = [SomeClass alloc] initializerThatMightReturnNil]
[anArray addObject:anObject]
```

This would throw an exception, if `anObject` is `nil`

So to answer your question: It is generally not necessary to check for `nil` after every initialization, just make sure you understand what happens if the object is nil.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I just added an example from one of Apple's tutorials. They allocate and initialize an NSMetadataQuery with an initializer that takes no arguments. And even if it did, I would think you would not want to hide your error by testing for nil...you would want an exception thrown so you'd be able to easily trace the bug when testing.  But in this case, I don't know why the reference would be nil immediately after initializing it with no arguments.

Comment: @Tenfour04 - There's a lot of weird stuff in Apple's examples.  There are specific cases where checking for nil is called for, but in the general case if nil is returned it's because the app environment is seriously effed up and so just letting things crash "naturally" is perfectly fine.

Comment: (Just to make sure the above comment is not taken out of context, we're talking about alloc/init calls here, not the general case of a method call that returns an object pointer.)

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, alloc/init can return `nil` without being seriously effed up, e.g. `initWithContentsOfFile:` or `initWithContentsOfURL:` on `NSArray` and `NSObject`. But I agree, if the docs don't mention a case where `init…` returns nil, there are other serious problems if it does.